# Combining multiple corpuses to train tagger

Tags: nltk

Is it possible to combine multiple corpuses to train tagger? For example I want to use treebank corpus, but I want to combine it with my custom corpus, since I miss in treebank such a words like 'php' (programming language) etc.

If I make my qustion more general then, how to train universal tagger using all available (or some) corpuses?

Comment: You can train a tagger with your own corpus, and you can set up your corpus reader to include whatever files you want. So, just define a super-corpus and put in everything you've got.

Comment: Look at the train-methods of the different taggers. You can train them with multiple data/corpora